How to control digital potentiometer MCP41010 using ESP32? (running into a weird error)
It is supposed to be a really simple task, but im running into an error:

E (23) gpio: GPIO can only be used as input mode

Here is the code I have used: (I am not even using GPIO 23, wtf is going on T_T)
#include <SPI.h>

const int CS_PIN = 35; // Chip Select pin
const int MOSI_PIN = 21; // Master Out Slave In
const int SCK_PIN = 18; // Clock pin
const int MISO_PIN = 19;
const int dummypin = 23;

//00010001 in hexadecimal this is taken from datasheet
#define CMD_WRITE 0x11

void setup() {
    SPI.begin(SCK_PIN, MISO_PIN, MOSI_PIN, CS_PIN);
    pinMode(dummypin, INPUT);
    pinMode(CS_PIN, OUTPUT);

    // Set CS high 
    digitalWrite(CS_PIN, HIGH);
}

void loop() {
    setPotentiometerValue(0); // Value range is 0-255
}

// Function to set potentiometer value
void setPotentiometerValue(uint8_t value) {
    // Bring CS low to select the MCP41010
    digitalWrite(CS_PIN, LOW);


    SPI.transfer(CMD_WRITE); // Command byte
    SPI.transfer(value); // to set pot value

    // Bring CS high to send the data (ig)
    digitalWrite(CS_PIN, HIGH);
}

Where am I going wrong T_T, I am not even using GPIO23
MCP41010: Datasheet

"I am not even using GPIO23". You're configuring GPIO23 as input (pinMode(dummypin, INPUT)). I'm not saying this is the issue, just an observation.

GPIO35 is input only. Choose a different GPIO for your CS.
